# Find the residue of $1/(z^2+1)^{n+1}$ at $z=i$.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

I'm trying to find the residue of $\frac{1}{(z^2+1)^{n+1}}$ at $z=i$.  I believe this should be approached combinatorially but I am getting stuck in the combinatorics.  Here's what I have so far.

$$ \frac{1}{(z^2+1)^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{(z-i)^{n+1}} \cdot \frac{1}{(z-i+2i)^{n+1}} $$

$$ = \frac{1}{(z-i)^{n+1}} \cdot \frac{1}{(2i)^{n+1}(1-[-z+i]/(2i))^{n+1}} $$

$$ = \frac{1}{(z-i)^{n+1}} \cdot \frac{1}{(2i)^{n+1}}\cdot \left[\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left((-z+i)/(2i)\right)^k\right]^{n+1} $$

$$ = \frac{1}{(z-i)^{n+1}} \cdot \frac{1}{(2i)^{n+1}}\cdot \left[\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{-1}{2i}\right)^k(z-i)^k\right]^{n+1} $$

To get the residues we want the $(z-i)^{-1}$ term, which we can determine once we know the $(z-i)^n$ term of the factor which is expressed above as a series.  This will come from making $n+1$ choices of a term from each of the $n+1$ copies of the series, such that the exponents sum to $n$.  However, this now gets into a pretty famous combinatorial problem of finding the ways to partition an integer.  That sounds like a lot of tricky combinatorial stuff when you're learning about residues.  Am I doing this the hard way--is there an easier one?

Comment: The residue of $\frac{f(z)}{(z-i)^{n+1}}$ at $z=i$ is closely related to $f^{(n)}(i)$.  Or, use the (generalized) binomial theorem $(1+z)^{\alpha} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{n} z^n$, and $\binom{-k}{n} = (-1)^n \binom{n+k-1}{n} = (-1)^n \binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$.  Or, even the way you're progressing is tractable seeing that it's *ordered* partitions you want to look at, so the combinatorial argument will be doable just using stars and bars.  Etc., etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we write $$g(z) = g(z_0)+g^\prime(z_0)(z-z_0) + g^{\prime \prime}(z_0)(z-z_0)^2 + \cdots$$ then $$\frac{g(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}= \frac{g(z_0)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}+\cdots+\frac{g^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!\,(z-z_0)}+ \frac{g^{(n+1)}(z_0)}{(n+1)!}+\frac{g^{(n+2)}(z_0)}{(n+2)!}(z-z_0)+\cdots,$$ so if $g(z)$ does not have poles or zeros at $z=z_0$, and $$\bbox[5px, border: 1pt solid green]{f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}},}$$ then the residue of $f(z)$ at $z=z_0$ is $$\bbox[5px, border: 1pt solid blue]{\text{Res}_{z=z_0}f(z) = \frac{g^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}.}$$

We have
$$\bbox[5px, border: 1.5pt solid green]{ f(z) = \frac{1}{(z+i)^{n+1}} \frac{1}{(z-i)^{n+1}}=\frac{g(z)}{(z-i)^{n+1}}}$$The residue of $f(z)$ at $z=i$ is thus

$$\bbox[5px, border: 1.5pt solid blue]{\text{Res}_{z=i} f(z) = \frac{ g^{(n)}(i)}{n!} = \frac{1}{i}\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}.}$$

Here is one way of computing the derivatives $\cdots$

$$g(z) = (z+i)^{-n-1}$$
$$g^\prime(z) = -(n+1) (z+i)^{-n-2}$$
$$g^{\prime\prime}(z) = (-1)^2 (n+1) (n+2) (z+i)^{-n-3}$$
$$\cdots$$
$$g^{(n)}(z) = (-1)^n \frac{(2n)!}{n!}(z+i)^{-2n-1}$$
$$g^{(n)}(i) = \frac{(2n)!}{n!} \frac{2^{-2n-1}}{i}$$

Comment: So I follow all of this, and thank you!  The formula you use for the residue was buried in a proof in my textbook, and not stated as a theorem, so I overlooked it.  But this makes perfect sense.  However, I have a question.  If you integrate $1/(x^2+1)^{n+1}$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ then this should come out to $2\pi i \cdot Res(f(z);i)$, right?  Yet the two answers do not seem to agree.

Comment: If it's unclear how I got this connection to the integral: I'm taking the closed semi-circular arc of "radius" $M$ in the upper half of the plane.  The arc part of the integral goes to 0 as $M\rightarrow \infty$ but the side along the real axis becomes the integral I wrote.

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty 1/(x^2+1) \,dx = \pi.$  Agrees.   $\int_{-\infty}^\infty 1/(x^2+1)^2 \, dx =\pi/2.$ Agrees. $\cdots.$

Comment: @Addem, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty 1/(x^2+1)^3 \, dx= 3\pi/8.$  Agrees.

Answer (score 1):

There is agreement between the residue and the integral of $f(x)$ along the real axis.  We show that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^{n+1}} = \frac{\pi}{2^{2n}a^{2n+1}} \frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}.$$

This is true for $n=0$:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2+a^2} = \frac{1}{a}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\frac{dx}{a} }{\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2}+1\right)}=\frac{1}{a} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dq}{q^2+1}=\frac{1}{a} \left.\tan^{-1} q\right|_{-\infty}^\infty=\frac{\pi}{a}.$$

Assume true for $n-1$ and differentiate with respect to $a$.

$$\frac{d}{da}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^{n}} = \frac{d}{da}\left[\frac{\pi}{2^{2n-2}a^{2n-1}} \frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!(n-1)!}\right].$$

$$-2 n a\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^{n+1}} =-(2n-1)\left[\frac{\pi}{2^{2n-2}a^{2n}} \frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!(n-1)!}\right].$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^{n+1}} =\frac{2n}{2n}\left[\frac{\pi}{2^{2n-1}a^{2n+1}} \frac{(2n-1)!}{n!(n-1)!}\right].$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^{n+1}} =\frac{\pi}{2^{2n}a^{2n+1}} \frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}.$$

With $a=1$,

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{(x^2+1)^{n+1}} =\frac{\pi}{2^{2n}} \frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}=2\pi i \cdot \text{Res}_{z=i}\, f(z).$$

Comment: So the reason they seemed to me to disagree is this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+1%2F%28x%5E2%2B1%29%5E%28n%2B1%29+dx+from+-infinity+to+infinity

Comment: I can see that the Gamma function with a fractional argument can be reconciled here because that introduces a square-root of $\pi$.  But I'm not seeing how the power of 2 gets reconciled here.  if the two agree, then I guess we must have that $\frac{\pi}{2^{2n}}\cdot\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!} = \frac{\pi \cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2n-1)}{2\cdot 4\cdots 2n}$.

Comment: ... Oh man, yeah, now I see it.  Never mind, I was being very slow.

Comment: @Addem,  No worries.  Glad you worked through it!